# Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256

Tags: ethereum, solidity

In the statement campaign.donations.push(amount); I am getting the following error:

**Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256.**

What's the problem and how to fix it please ?

```
function donateToCampaign(uint256 _id) public payable {
        uint256 amount = msg.value;

        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];

        campaign.donators.push(msg.sender);
        campaign.donations.push(amount);

        (bool sent, ) = payable(campaign.owner).call{value: amount}("");

        if (sent) {
            campaign.amountCollected = campaign.amountCollected + amount;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show the `Campaign` definition, but based on the context I'm assuming that its `donations` member is of type `uint256`

```
struct Campaign {
    // ...
    uint256 donations;
    // ...
}
```

This effectively means that you can store one number in `donations` - not multiple numbers.

---

If you want to increase the current value of `donations`, use the plus sign.

```
campaign.donations += amount;
```

If you want to store each donation amount separately, then you need to change the type of `donations` to `uint256[]` (an array of numbers).

```
struct Campaign {
    // ...
    uint256[] donations;
    // ...
}
```

This way you're able to store multiple numbers (of type `uint256`) in the array.

```
campaign.donations.push(amount);
```